# When redirecting the user via Ajax and Js, the source code of the file is displayed, instead of the graphical interface

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm currently working on a school project involving the implementation of a login system using PHP (with PDO), JavaScript, and Ajax. The goal is to redirect users to their respective dashboards based on their user types. However, I've encountered an issue where, instead of displaying the intended dashboard, the web browser shows the source code, including the underlying structure. I have attached the code files for reference.

User-controller.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once("db.php");
    require_once('class.php');
    require_once('user-model.php');

    session_start();

    $response = array(); // Initialize the $response variable

    if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
       $mail = $_POST['user'];
       $contra = $_POST['pass'];

       $databaseCuatro = new Database();
       $conn = $databaseCuatro->getConnection();
       $sql = "SELECT email, contrasena, rol FROM usuarios WHERE email = 
       :mail";
       $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $mail);
       $stmt->execute();

        $usuario = $stmt->fetch();

        if ($usuario && password_verify($contra, $usuario['contrasena'])) 
    {
            // Valid credentials, create the session
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

        // Set the status based on the user's role
        if ($usuario['rol'] === 1) {
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $usuario;
            $response['status'] = 1;
        } elseif ($usuario['rol'] === 2) {
            $_SESSION['userdem'] = $usuario;
            $response['status'] = 2;
        } elseif ($usuario['rol'] === 3) {
            $_SESSION['useroferente'] = $usuario;
            $response['status'] = 3;
        }
    } else {
        $conn = $databaseCuatro->getConnection();

        if (!$databaseCuatro->checkMail($mail)) {
            $response['status'] = 5; // Email does not exist
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 4; // Incorrect username or password
          }
       }
    }

    // Now send the JSON response
    header('Content-Type: application/json;');

    echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

script-forms.js:

```
    /* Ajax for login */
    function loginData(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting 
     immediately

    var user = $('.input-user').val();
    var pass = $('.input-pass').val();

      let data = {
        user: user,
        pass: pass
      }

      /* Check login using Ajax */
      $.ajax({
      url: "user-controller.php",
      method: "post",
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
          if (response.status === 1) {
                  window.location.href = 'dashboard-admin.php';
              } else if (response.status === 2) {
                 window.location.href = 'dashboard-demandante.php';
              } else if (response.status === 3) {
                  window.location.href = 'dashboard-oferente.php';
              } else if (response.status === 4) {
                  showMessage("Incorrect username or password!");
              } else if (response.status === 5) {
                  showMessage("This account does not exist!");
              }
          },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("Error in AJAX request: " + error);
          }
      });
    }
```

This is one of the dashboards(all of them are giving me the same problem)

````
```<?php
include_once('db.php');
include_once('class.php');
include_once('user-controller.php');
include('header-admin.html');

if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true) {
    $admin = $_SESSION['admin'];
} else {
    header('Location: user-form.php');
    exit();
}

$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->getConnection();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE MailA = :mail";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':mail', $mail); 
$stmt->execute();
$adminData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$conexion = null;
?>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h2> Bienvenido Administrador!</h2>
                </div>   
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="input-group justify-content-center  
align-items-center">
                    <form method="POST" action="dashboard-admin.php">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
name="btnPerfiles">Ver Perfiles</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" 
name="logoutAd">Logout</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnPerfiles'])) {
    header('Location: admin-perfiles.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['logoutAd'])) {
    header('Location: user-form.php');
    session_destroy();
}
?>```
````

[image]

Comment: in 99% of cases this happens because you're not  running the code in an environment which supports PHP. Make sure you use a proper webserver on your development machine with access via `http://localhost`

Comment: P.S. `instead of displaying the intended dashboard`....so is it redirecting you to (for example) `dashboard-admin.php` and _then_ displaying source code instead of that dashboard contents? Or do you mean the problem is occuring on some other page before that? It wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: Seems a little odd, if the user_controller works the other PHP code should work

Comment: Hi @ADyson , when I log in, Js sends me to the dashboard corresponding to the type of user, but instead of seeing the web page (the html structure, with the css) I see the source code of the file (dashboard).

Comment: That's really bizarre...so the login script at User-Controller.php is working correctly, but then the dashboard one isn't? So it seems unlikely to be an environment-related issue then, probably more likely something in the dashboard page. Can you [edit] your question and paste the code of one of the dashboard PHP files which is giving you a problem, please

Comment: @RiggsFolly the user_controller works fine,but the problem still there

Comment: And can we please see a screenshot of your browser when you try to visit this dashboard page. That would help too. Thanks. (Sorry I should have asked for this before)

Comment: @ADyson sorry, Im not allowe to upload pictures to my post yet, I paste the likn of my drive so you can see the picture

Comment: That link actually pointed to imgur, not Drive. I edited it, all you have to do to make it inline is add a `!` before it.

Comment: Anyway, the problem seems to occur before anything you've shown here. I'd guess the issue is because of `include('header-admin.html');`...you `include` this inside a PHP code block, but it's not a PHP file and no doubt does not have a `?>` to close the block and start raw output again (and unless you rename it with `.php`, `?>` and `<?php` wouldn't work anyway). So you need to rename it `.php` at the very least, then PHP will treat it properly. You may also need the close and open code blocks too at both ends, to indicate to PHP that the content in between is literal output, not PHP code

Comment: @ADyson i make the changes that u said,but still not workin

Comment: Do you still get exactly the same result? Can you update the post so I can see exactly what you changed?

Comment: P.S. as an aside, another obvious problem you've got is that `<div class="container mt-4">` ...etc is all being added at the end of the HTML document, _after_ the closing `</html>` tag. This makes no sense and invalidates your page as a HTML document. I suspect you need to split up your "header" file into separate "header" and "footer" files, and include the closing `</body></html>` tags only in the footer file, which you should `require_once` at the _end_ of your dashboard page, after all of the other contents.